# Check for changes in 2 inputs and enable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a series of radio items. If a user chooses a specific entry on one of the radio items (missing item) I use JQuery to add a bootstrap is-invalid class to two specific inputs on the form along with a label asking them to add detail and disable the submit button to stop them submitting the form.

```
$(function () {
$("input[name=optradio]:radio").click(function () {
  if ($('input[name=optradio]:checked').val() == "2") {
      $('textarea[name=sentTo]').addClass('is-invalid');
      $('input[name=dateSent]').addClass('is-invalid');
      $('#removedMSG').text("You must update this field prior to saving");
      $('#removedMSG2').text("You must update this field prior to saving");
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
      $('textarea[name=sentTo]').removeClass('is-invalid');
      $('input[name=dateSent]').removeClass('is-invalid');
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
});
```

I would like to add further checks to make sure the user updates the two inputs (ones a textarea) before I re-enable the submit button.

I know I can use the following to check for input changes

```
$("textarea[name=sentTo]").on("input", function(){
   $('textarea[name=sentTo]').removeClass('is-invalid');
});
```

This works fine. However I am at a loss how to integrate it all together:

So basically user selects the radio, is-invalid gets added to 2 input fields and the submit button disabled - user completes 2 fields as required and only when both fields have been updated do we then re-enable the submit button.

I am thinking I need an if statement but I can't seem to get the code right.

I tried

```
if `$("textarea[name=sentTo]").on("input") && $("textarea[name=dateSent]").on("input")`
```

but this doesnt work

Thanks to Mamum I am using the code below.

```
$(function () {
$('input[name=optradio]:radio').click(function () {
  if ($('input[name=optradio]:checked').val() == "2") {
      $('textarea[name=sentTo]').addClass('is-invalid');
      $('input[name=dateSent]').addClass('is-invalid');
      $('#removedMSG').text("You must update this field prior to saving");
      $('#removedMSG2').text("You must update this field prior to saving");
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#submit').addClass('btn-danger');
      $('#submit').removeClass('btn-primary');
  } else {
      $('textarea[name=sentTo]').removeClass('is-invalid');
      $('input[name=dateSent]').removeClass('is-invalid');
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#submit').addClass('btn-primary');
      $('#submit').removeClass('btn-danger');
  }
 });
});

var sentTo = false;
var dateSent = false;
$("textarea[name=sentTo], input[name=dateSent]").on("input", function(){
if($(this).attr('name') == 'sentTo') {
  sentTo = true;
  $(this).removeClass('is-invalid');
}
if($(this).attr('name') == 'dateSent') {
  dateSent = true;
  $(this).removeClass('is-invalid');
}
if(sentTo && dateSent){
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#submit').addClass('btn-primary');
  $('#submit').removeClass('btn-danger');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple selector separated by comma and use `this` keyword to refer the current element inside the event handler function:

```
var sentTo = dateSent = false;
$("textarea[name=sentTo], textarea[name=dateSent]").on("input", function(){
  if($(this).attr('name') == 'sentTo') sentTo = true;    //true for sentTo
  if($(this).attr('name') == 'dateSent') dateSent = true;//true for dateSent
  if(sentTo && dateSent){  // if both are true
    $(this).removeClass('is-invalid');
    sentTo = dateSent = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way of using this to only run the code if both sentTo and dateSent are changed and not just one?

Comment: @MatthewBarraud, you can try the way in the updated answer:)